# Karate Cucumber Report | Why cucumber report displays rows for all tags?

Tags: karate

I'm using Karate DSL's parallel runner to run my API tests. It is using cucumber reporting library to generate test results.I have question about 'Tags' section of cucumber report.

Here is my sample feature file.

```
@tag1 @tag2
Feature: Test

Background:
  Given url testUrl

Scenario Outline: Test scenario

  Given path 'test'
  And param parameter = <parameter>
  When method GET
  Then status 200

  Examples:
    | parameter |
    | 123 |
    | 456 |
```

**Issue:**
If I run test with only tag @tag1, I'm expecting to see only @tag1 in 'Tags' section of the report, but It's displaying rows for both @tag1 and @tag2.

**Questions:**
1. Is it expected behavior in cucumber report ?
2. Is there a way to customize report to only include specified tag ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have some mistake when you ran the tests.

Refer this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51839405/143475

If that doesn't help please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

EDIT: have responded and closed the issue you raised.

Comment: I tried stackoverflow link. I did not help.                                                                   Created issue # https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/665

Comment: Reported Issue in cucumber-report - https://github.com/damianszczepanik/cucumber-reporting/issues/812